# Getting "TypeError ctx[0].data is undefined" in Svelte

Tags: graphql, svelte, apollo-server

I'm trying to get started with both GraphQL and Svelte using Apollo Server, but all I get is this error "ctx[random number].data is undefined". I also tried svelte {#async} but got the same error. What I'm doing wrong and how to make it works?

```
    <script>
  import { InMemoryCache } from "@apollo/client/core";
  import { SvelteApolloClient } from "svelte-apollo-client";
  import { gql } from "@apollo/client/core";

  const client = new SvelteApolloClient({
    uri:
      "https://graphql.contentful.com/content/v1/spaces/4x1ftgol5cf4/explore?access_token=VhWS6Pydw4xIoh0-bo2b7ANxmHxj_698UMVpy8JfmkY",
    cache: new InMemoryCache()
  });

  let data = client.query(gql`
    query {
      mellunarModaCollection {
        items {
          sys {
            id
          }
          title
          price
          img {
            url
          }
          off
        }
      }
    }
  `);
</script>

<style>
</style>
<ul>
      {#each $data.data.mellunarModaCollection.items as item}
        <li>
          <h2>{item.title}</h2>
          <h4>{item.price}</h4>
          <img src={item.img.url} alt={item.title} />
        </li>
      {/each}
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow the example on Svelte Apollo Client's [page](https://github.com/timhall/svelte-apollo)

```
{#if $data.loading }
  Loading...
{:else if $data.error}
  Error {$data.error.message}
{:else}
  <ul>
    {#each $data.data.mellunarModaCollection.items as item}
      <li>
        <h2>{item.title}</h2>
        <h4>{item.price}</h4>
        <img src={item.img.url} alt={item.title} />
      </li>
    {/each}
  </ul>
{/if}
```

Or at the very least wrap your html code between `{#if $data.data} ... {/if}`

Here the `ctx[random number]` corresponds to `$data`, the error is that `$data.data` is undefined. It is undefined because the query didn't have time yet to run.